# Do/While loop incrementation, generating stars whereby each row increments by one star

Tags: c#

1. How can I increment stars in a do while loop not for loop.

Output should be :

```
*  
**  
***  
****
```

2. How to assign `i` to `"*"` in following

```
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("{i}", i);
    i++;
} while (i <= 10);
```

Comment: `do { Console.WriteLine($"{new string('*',i)}", i); i++; } while (i <= 10);`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are looking to write a number of "asterixis" on a single line based on a do-while. A simple solution would be:

```cs
int i = 0;
do
{
    Console.WriteLine(new String('*', i));
    i++;
} while (i <= 10);
```

Although I may not be understanding your question

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see the reformatted question

Comment: not asterixis but each star on a line

Comment: The solution above outputs in the same format in the question